# Initializing superclasses Python3

Tags: python-3.x, inheritance, initialization

I am trying to understand when to initialize a superclass when using inheritance in python. Initially I thought that just by declaring a class inheriting from a super class, ex. class my_class(superclass):, would make available all the superclass's attributes and methods to the subclass. Which makes sense for somebody coming from Java. Then I read that Python forces us to initialize superclasses before we can implement them in our subclass, either by using the superclass.**init**() or super().**init**(). Then I came across this piece of code where I am not initializing the parent's class, however Python gave me access to the self.queue attribute from superclass without having initialized the parent class. I read the Python documentation and sometimes I think I know what they mean and some other I dont. Can anyone please explain to me when do we have to initialize superclasses in our subclasses?

```
class QueueError(IndexError):
pass

class Queue:
    def __init__(self):
       self.queue = []
    def put(self,elem):
       self.queue.insert(0,elem)
    def get(self):
        if len(self.queue) > 0:
            elem = self.queue[-1]
            del self.queue[-1]
            return elem
        else:
            raise QueueError

    class SuperQueue(Queue):
    def isempty(self):
        if not self.queue:
            return True
        else:
            return False

que = SuperQueue()
que.put(1)
que.put("dog")
que.put(False)
for i in range(4):
    if not que.isempty():
        print(que.get())
    else:
        print("Queue empty")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, if you override `__init__` in your subclass, you should call the super `__init__` method only. This is necessary if you extend the superclass. But if you want to overwrite the whole `__init__`, you can also omit the super call.

**Example:**

You have class `A` that has one attribute `value1`.
And now you need a second attribute, so you subclass `A` with `B` and overwrite the `__init__` where you call the super class (`A`), so `A` can set `value1` and in `B` you can not set `value2`.
But now you need some other attributes in `C`, but need the same methods as in `A`. So you can entirely overwrite `__init__` and omit the super call to `A`.

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, value1):
        print("Initialize A")
        self.value1 = value1


class B(A):
    def __init__(self, value1, value2):
        super().__init__(value1)
        print("Initialize B")
        self.value2 = value2


class C(A):
    def __init__(self, value3):
        print("Initialize C")
        self.value3 = value3


a = A("foo")
b = B("foo", "bar")
c = C("baz")

print(a.value1)
print(b.value1, b.value2)
print(c.value3)
print(c.value1)
```

Output

```
$ python main.py
Initialize A
Initialize A
Initialize B
Initialize C
foo
foo bar
baz
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 27, in <module>
    print(c.value1)
AttributeError: 'C' object has no attribute 'value1'
```

You can see `C` wasn't initialized with `value1`, because `C` didn't call `A`'s `__init__`.

Comment: In other words, we can says that a subclass automatically inherits all of the superclass's traits. But if a subclass tries to access the superclass traits, it will generate an AttributeError exception, only if we override the superclass __init__. Now I see what super().__init__() is doing, it is basically giving a subclass access to the superclass' traits defined in the superclass __init__ when this one has been overrided in the subclass. Thank you.